# how to preserve textbox data in jsp even after clicking the refresh button

Tags: html, jsp

this is my jsp page

```
<html>
   <body>
  <span>User name:</span> <input type="text" name="Teachername" value="<%=request.getParameter("name") %>" class="input_panel" id="Username" readonly/><br><br><br>
  <span>Old password:</span> <input type="password" name="TeacherOpwd" class="input_panel" id="TeacherOpwd" /><br><br><br>
  <span>New password:</span> <input type="password" name="TeacherNpwd" class="input_panel" id="TeacherNpwd" /><br><br><br>

 <input type="submit" id="TeacherSubmit" name="submit" class="submit_button" value=" "  />
</body></html>
```

i need, whatever i write on the textbox remain unchanged after refreshing the page.
please help..

Comment: How did you calling page refreshing through javascript or R-click->refresh

Comment: Make it `uneditable` using the `readonly` property

Comment: and what if when i come from any other jsp page

Comment: @Subodh: Can you explain what exactly you mean by the above statement?

Comment: Another option is to store the value as cookie and update the field on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's not how HTML/JSP works. If you want to do something like this you should look at implementing some form of MVVM pattern, or using a framework which supports it. (ZK, AngularJS or KnockoutJS).

For more information, read the [Wikipedia article on MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, data must be preserved for later availability after refresh.

So, as and when you write, there must be some way which is doing the work of storing in background, so that when refresh happens, it can take the data from stored place.

I have not found requirement like this before but can think like you can go with Ajax for this and once you get the data at server, try storing it in cookie and when refresh happens, first try to read from cookie if available or else show blank.

Also, check is there any way you can store it at javascript level, as I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

use HttpSession session = request.getSession(); session.setAttribute("someItem")

after you click the button. It should still be there.